# Idiomatic iterator for a linear function

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

A while back, I asked a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80592/converting-an-array-returning-function-to-a-lazy-evaluator) about implementing an idiomatic iterator in C++. I've recently revisited the code, and I'm bothered by the duplication in the begin and end iterators. The code goes over a collection/iterator over a domain, and lazily produces the range using the iterator. After trimming down some code from the accepted answer, here's what I have:

```
class LinearFunction
{
public:
    LinearFunction(double m, double b) : m_(m), b_(b) { }

    double operator()(double x) const { return m_ * x + b_; }
private:
    double m_, b_;

};

template <typename IterType>
class LinearFunctionIterator
{
public:
    LinearFunctionIterator(IterType iter, LinearFunction const &linearFunction)
        : xIter_(iter), linearFunction_(linearFunction) { }

    LinearFunctionIterator &operator++() { 
        ++xIter_; 
        return *this;
    }

    double operator*() const {
        return linearFunction_(*xIter_);
    }

    bool operator!=(LinearFunctionIterator const &other) const { 
        return xIter_ != other.xIter_;
    } 

private:
    IterType xIter_;
    LinearFunction linearFunction_; // <--- (1)
};


template <typename IterType>
class LinearFunctionIteratorProxy
{
public:
    LinearFunctionIteratorProxy(IterType xBegin, IterType xEnd,
                                LinearFunction const &linearFunction)
        : xBegin_(xBegin), xEnd_(xEnd), linearFunction_(linearFunction) { }

    LinearFunctionIterator<IterType> begin() const {
        return { xBegin_, linearFunction_ };
    }

    LinearFunctionIterator<IterType> end() const {
        return { xEnd_, linearFunction_ };
    }

private:
    IterType xBegin_, xEnd_;
    LinearFunction linearFunction_;
};


template<typename Container>
auto makeLinearFunction(Container const &domain, 
                        LinearFunction const &linearFunction) 
-> LinearFunctionIteratorProxy<decltype(std::begin(domain))> 
{
    return { std::begin(domain), std::end(domain), linearFunction };
}
```

Usage:

```
#include "LinearFunction.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> domain { 1.0, 5.0, 2.0, 8.0 };
    LinearFunction linearFunction(10.0, 5.0);

    std::cout << "Range:\n";
    for(auto rangeValue : makeLinearFunction(domain, linearFunction))
    {
        std::cout << rangeValue << ", ";
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for from the review:

1. Notice in the example usage, that there are three copies of the `LinearFunction` instance: one in the proxy, one in the `begin` iterator, and one in the `end`. Is there a better way to achieve the same behavior without this duplication?
2. General advice to improve this code would be appreciated.

Comment: The language tag in the title isn't really necessary.

Comment: I suppose that can be argued, but "Idiomatic" is different for different languages, no?

Comment: Yes, but anyone checking the question will know it corresponds to C++.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, you're the mod :) Do you have a suggestion for improving the code? I see from your profile that you have a high rep for C++ code reviews

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make begin() and end() hold references (instead of copies)? (maybe it's obvious, but I don't write much C++ anymore)

Comment: I can take a look at it, but there are others who are more experienced with iterators.

Comment: @PierreMenard, I thought about it, but (I think) I found an edge-case: If I try to use my iterator with something like [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), how would I implement `operator=()`? would I just copy `xIter_`? I suppose that works, but I'd like to see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 3):

- I suppose that if you don't really have a need to end member names with underscores, then you can avoid them.  Having similar names as constructor parameters won't even matter as long as you're using an initializer list.
- Probably a bit nit-picky, but you may not need the precision of a `double` here.  If so, then you can just use `float`s.
- With `begin()` and `end()`, you can also provide `const` versions (`cbegin()` and `cend()`).

  Also, be careful with these names since they're also used in the STL.  You may also use slightly different names if you prefer.
- If you really need `operator!=`, then you should also provide `operator==`.

  In addition, it's usually preferred to define `operator!=` in terms of `==`:

  ```
  return !(xIter_ == other.xIter_);
  ```

Comment: Some interesting points. I should point out that the use of `begin()` and `end()` is deliberate. This is so they can work with the `<algorithm>` library, (hence the idiomatic requirement). Also, regarding the last point, `makeLinearFunction()` is only called once (since this is a range based for loop, this is equivalent to: `auto linearFunction = makeLinearFunction(...); for(auto it = std::begin(linearFunction); it != std::end(linearFunction); ++it) { ... };`)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.  It just looked a little odd to have that in the loop statement anyway.